# What is the PHP config file for Nginx?

Tags: nginx, config, php

When I wanted to show/hide PHP errors, in Apache, I changed the PHP configuration file that was under `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

In *Nginx* I have no idea of where is the appropriate file, I'd only found this one: `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

But the configuration there doesn't seems to be correct.

If I modify the `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` file, the configuration declared there will take effects for all my *Nginx* *sites available*?

Comment: `phpinfo` would tell you but yes, that's the right ini file.  You'll need to restart `php-fpm` for any  changes to take effect.

Comment: @AD7six worked perfect! Please post it as an asnwer

Comment: did you restart php after editing ? `sudo service php5-fpm reload`

Comment: As @AD7six said it, yes I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I modify the /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini file, the configuration declared there will take effects for all my Nginx *sites available*?

### Yes

To confirm, put the following in a web accessible location and request it via a browser:

```
<?= phpinfo();
```

The parsed ini files will be listed.

### Restart the right process

You may notice that restarting `nginx` does not reflect changes made to php ini files, this is to be expected.

In contrast to using php with e.g. apache; be sure to restart `php-fpm` for changes to take effect.

Comment: I've restarted the process with: `sudo service php5-fpm restart`